# The new theme has a lot of space between impact and bottom parts

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

In the new update, there is a huge gap between the impact and the below section.
[image]

Comment: I love how they've fixed the alignment issues, but now hate the spacing. We are not easily pleased it seems :/

Comment: This is by design because the content within the other highlight boxes can fluctuate.

Comment: For me it looks totally off.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3o3X.jpg random spaces and line breaks everywhere..

Comment: @Hynes another one. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBfQo.png this should be changed to previous style. Near the tag score

Comment: @Floern Yep, same here. Gears are "off again" :) Gonna lean back with a coke and see all those bug reports rollin' in again :)

Comment: Huh. On my personal meta user it's fine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF92Y.png Not on SO though https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9LVh.png

Comment: @SagarV Not sure what bug you're reporting. The gear icons have been moved. If the stacked gear icons are confusing, I can swap the first gear icon since it only toggles what your tracking—not allow to select that exact thing your tracking.

Comment: I mean the label next badge gear icon should be moved to previous place. I mean the right side of tag score. @Hynes

Comment: @SagarV I'm still not following you. Can you create a new post with your issue?

Comment: @Hynes SagarV is saying that before the top gear icon was on the right of the score, and they think it should stay there

Comment: @CalvT븃 The gear next to the label "Next tag badge" is a menu toggle that allows to track a tag badge or a privilege. The gear icon next to the tag badge itself allows you to select a different tag badge to track.

Comment: @CalvT븃 Of which score? The rep increase?

Comment: This one @Hynes https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFaxi.png

Comment: @Hynes look at this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDqpW.png - see the gear on the right in the blue box? That's what's being talked about

Comment: Exactly @CalvT븃 I searched a lot in my pc. but can't find an old screenshot of activity tab. Thanks for that image

Comment: @CalvT븃 Thanks for the screenshot. I'll look into it. I can move it to be over with the progress bars, but it won't be in the box margins any longer. Those have all been moved to be within the box now.

Comment: @Hynes one suggestion for this post. If you increase the font size of **IMPACT** and move it to the center, you can bring the impact count a little down and the spacing issue will be resolved

Comment: @SagarV Thanks for the suggestion. I'll play with a couple things and see if I can lessen the whitespace.

Comment: @Hynes I mean like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQIUC.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Impact box layout has been slightly updated to reduce some of the trapped whitespace. It now looks like this:

[image: Impact]

This is now live and in production.

Also within the comments there was a request to move the badge / privilege tracker menu toggle. This has been moved to the far right:

[image: UX.SE menu toggle]

Comment: Thing is that I noticed this morning, is that the 3rd box on the right under **"Impact"** with the flags is smaller and am seeing *"6,184 posts edited"* and 
*"1,246 helpful flags"* appear under 2 lines, rather than what used to be on 1 line for each.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351392/profile-page-is-squished-edit-flag-votes-stats-are-wrapping-and-look-bad

Comment: I see @Matt thanks. Seems like it's getting some mixed reactions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- community support seems to be unanimously in favor, so far, actually. Extremely small sample size, though.

Comment: @TylerH Majority rules then *lol*

Comment: @TylerH Yet, it doesn't mean that they're right though ;-) or that it works in favor for everyone. I myself don't like the new design fit. It's not that "uniform", and uniform for who really?

Comment: @Fred-ii- the uniform grid system doesn't mean the grids are all the same size but that they take up set ratios and/or percentages of space. Templated layouts are easier to modify and iterate over because you can rely on surrounding elements to grow or shrink as needed if you need to make an adjustment somewhere. Custom layouts require you to modify everything even if you just want to make a change in one place.